# How to use advanced query without nil output when selecting a count in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm  working through a practice project to create a short-url.

I have the following classes/tables:

- `shortened_urls` which holds a short url, long url, and user.
- `user` which holds user info.
- `visit` which is a joins table for who visited what links.
- `tag_topics` which holds categories for tagging URLs.
- `tagging` which is a joins table that links shortened URLs to a tag.

I'm trying to

> "write a method, `TagTopic#popular_links` that returns the 5 most visited links for that 'TagTopic' along with the number of times each link has been clicked."

I started with:

```
def popular_links
    shortened_urls.joins(:visits)
end
```

which gave the following output in the videos tag. For example:

```
  ShortenedUrl Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "shortened_urls".* FROM "shortened_urls" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "shortened_urls"."id" = "taggings"."shortened_url_id" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "visits"."shortened_url_id" = "shortened_urls"."id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_topic_id" = $1  [["tag_topic_id", 2]]
[#<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7caee5298
  id: 2,
  short_url: "G6hSOkznliIwHxMUV1BPug",
  long_url: "imdb.com",
  user_id: 2,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00>,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7cbd04e00
  id: 3,
  short_url: "kFf-yYHHUZZFBYEy__K9sw",
  long_url: "youtube.com",
  user_id: 3,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00>,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7cbd04ba8
  id: 3,
  short_url: "kFf-yYHHUZZFBYEy__K9sw",
  long_url: "youtube.com",
  user_id: 3,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00>,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7cbd04928
  id: 3,
  short_url: "kFf-yYHHUZZFBYEy__K9sw",
  long_url: "youtube.com",
  user_id: 3,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00>,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7cbd04798
  id: 3,
  short_url: "kFf-yYHHUZZFBYEy__K9sw",
  long_url: "youtube.com",
  user_id: 3,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00>,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7cbd045b8
  id: 4,
  short_url: "DZa0WvFrMcRjL2EQAFdWyg",
  long_url: "plex.tv",
  user_id: 3,
  created_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 21:07:36 UTC +00:00>]
```

But when I try doing any  selecting or counting, (this was originally the solution provided):

```
def popular_links
    shortened_urls.joins(:visits)
      .group(:short_url, :long_url)
      .order('COUNT(visits.id) DESC')
      .select('long_url, short_url, COUNT(visits.id) as number_of_visits')
      .limit(5)
end
```

I get the following output:

```
 ShortenedUrl Load (2.1ms)  SELECT long_url, short_url, COUNT(visits.id) as number_of_visits FROM "shortened_urls" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "shortened_urls"."id" = "taggings"."shortened_url_id" INNER JOIN "visits" ON "visits"."shortened_url_id" = "shortened_urls"."id" WHERE "taggings"."tag_topic_id" = $1 GROUP BY "shortened_urls"."short_url", "shortened_urls"."long_url" ORDER BY COUNT(visits.id) DESC LIMIT $2  [["tag_topic_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 5]]
[#<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7d21431c8
  id: nil,
  short_url: "kFf-yYHHUZZFBYEy__K9sw",
  long_url: "youtube.com">,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7d20ebd38
  id: nil,
  short_url: "DZa0WvFrMcRjL2EQAFdWyg",
  long_url: "plex.tv">,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00007fc7d20ebc48
  id: nil,
  short_url: "G6hSOkznliIwHxMUV1BPug",
  long_url: "imdb.com">]
```

There is no "count," and the id is nil. The URLs will select though. I tried re-arranging, or doing different selections, but it never seems to return a count. From looking at the `select all` on the joins table, it should be able to count. I'm not sure if I'm querying wrong or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no "count"

What you are seeing is actually what happens when you inspect a model - not the actual result rows from the database. It will only ever show the attributes of the model that are created by reading the database schema. Its just a debugging aid.

If you actually iterate though the records the attribute is actually there.

```
popular_links.each do |url|
  puts url.number_of_visits
end
```

Protip is to write unit tests instead of just staring blindly at the console.

> and the id shows as nil.

That's because you are not selecting the id.

```
.select(:id, :long_url, :short_url, 'COUNT(visits.id) as number_of_visits')
```